# pyodbc python linux iSeriesAccess driver - stored procedure - capture output parameters?

Tags: linux, ibm-midrange, pyodbc, db2-400

I've read thru several threads discussing this -- however - not finding an option which appears to be the right first for my use case.

Linux (RHEL 7.x)
- IBM iSeriesAccess driver
- Connecting to AS/400
- Python/pyodbc (ibm_db does not seem to support the iSeriesAccess driver)

Call to stored procedure -- call works well - data is returned as expected. Issue is this is a set of procedures which have been in place for several years and also used by other systems and while the other systems (i.e. SQL Server) are able to retrieve the output parameter correctly we are finding this to be a challenge with pyodbc.

Using a very basic script to describe this -- only expected data rows are in the result set -- not the output parameter (which is the example I've seen on other threads to capture the output parameter.

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect("dsn=DEV; UID=USER; PWD=PASSWD")
if connection:
   crsr = connection.cursor()

   # PARM 2 is an OUTPUT parameter type
   parms = (23,0)
   crsr.execute("{CALL GET_DATA(?, ?)}", parms)

   rows = crsr.fetchall()
   while rows:
        print(rows)
        if crsr.nextset():
           rows = crsr.fetchall()
        else:
           rows = None
else:
   print connection
   print "error connection"
```

Comment: Have you tried using an anonymous code block similar to what is described [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures#output-parameters-and-return-values)?

Comment: code block from the stored procedure aspect? If this is the context referred to that is an issue as we have the procedures used by several other systems and we are not in a position to modify.

Comment: No, just a block of code you execute from your Python script. It doesn't modify the stored procedure, it calls the stored procedure and then uses a SELECT statement to return the output parameter(s) as a single-row result set.

Comment: I'll see if I can create the setup in the DB2 syntax that is also supported thru CLP/CLI for AS400 --

Comment: At this point I've not found a supportable option for an anonymous code block to use with DB2 (i5).  The general error returned is pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', u'[HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Error in host server data stream. (30187) (SQLPrepare)') 

Fails -- 
      sql= """\
         BEGIN
            CALL GET_MSTR_ALMSTP(23, ?);
         END

      """

Works ---
      sql= """\
            CALL GET_MSTR_ALMSTP(23, ?);
      """

Comment: Any chance someone has a sample of using python on Linux (RHEL) which captures the proc output parameter value when calling DB2 (i5/AS400) via ODBC? ... we should be able to work with most any code type; python, java, etc.

Answer (score 1):

So it appears that PyODBC does not implement `callproc`. They do document a [way](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures#output-parameters-and-return-values) to get around this limitation for certain databases, but that will not work for Db2. The only way I can see to get the values is to use global variables:

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect("dsn=DEV; UID=USER; PWD=PASSWD")
if connection:
   crsr = connection.cursor()

   crsr.execute("create or replace variable out_parm integer default 0"))

   crsr.execute("call GET_DATA(?, out_parm)", (23,))

   rows = crsr.fetchall()
   while rows:
        print(rows)
        if crsr.nextset():
           rows = crsr.fetchall()
        else:
           rows = None

   crsr.execute("values(out_parm)")
   print(crsr.fetchall())
else:
   print connection
   print "error connection"
```

**Original Answer:**

You need to use [callproc](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#callproc) instead of `execute`.

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect("dsn=DEV; UID=USER; PWD=PASSWD")
if connection:
   crsr = connection.cursor()

   # PARM 2 is an OUTPUT parameter type
   parms = (23,0)
   out_parms = crsr.callproc("GET_DATA", parms)

   rows = crsr.fetchall()
   while rows:
        print(rows)
        if crsr.nextset():
           rows = crsr.fetchall()
        else:
           rows = None
else:
   print connection
   print "error connection"
```

Comment: The `.callproc` method is optional and pyodbc does not implement it.

Comment: @GordThompson, you are correct. I did not realize that PyODBC did not implement output parameter support. I have updated my answer with a way to do it, but it's not exactly pretty and may not be easily feasible if you don't have authority to create global variables.